# Write enum to DB as lowercase value

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I am getting a @RequestBody where one of the fields is an enum in my model.

ie

```
public enum X{  
   VALUE("Value")
}
```

I am able to pass in "Value" with the request which gets mapped to the correct enum value just fine. But when I save the body to the database it saves it as "VALUE". Is there some annotation or relatively easy way to save it as "Value" in the DB?

my fallback option is to just rename the enum to Value.